# How can I improve efficiency with large datasets (at least I think they're large)?

Tags: database-design

I have a database that is modeling data similar to the kind of data you might see collected for sports. I have *users* and *events*, and *users* have *roles* at these *events*. Each of these *events* also has *stats* and belongs to a *category*, that are all currently related so:

```
=========  ========== ============
| users |  | events | | category |
|=======|  |========| |==========|
| id    |  | id     | | id       |
---------  ---------- ------------

=========================    =======================
| roles                 |    | stats               |
|=======================|    |=====================|
| id                    |    |id                   |
| user_id -> users.id   |    | role_id -> roles.id |
| event_id -> events.id |    -----------------------
| category_id -> cat... |
-------------------------
```

I have been going about this trying to keep everything very well separated and normalized, but I'm starting to see a major efficiency trade off. Data is added in batches, and by a rough estimate there are about rows of *stats* per event, and I am pulling in hundreds of events at one time. Currently I have am toying with only one *user* and have 170,000 *stats*, and this is probably a quarter of this *user*'s * *stats*.

Here's an example of how I might be querying this:

```
SELECT avg(some_data) FROM stats
    JOIN roles ON stats.role_id = roles.id
    JOIN users ON roles.user_id = roles.id
    JOIN events ON roles.event_id = events.id
    JOIN categories ON roles.category_id = categories.id
        WHERE users.u_thing = 'something'
            AND categories.name = 'something'
    GROUP BY stats.timestamp
```

This query (on a virtual host, granted) is taking on average 8 seconds, and is performing `avg()` over 14000 rows.

I'm not particularly familiar with database architecture or design, so I am not sure what I can do here to optimize my schema / access patterns.

**Addtional**

- Caching results is a limited utility here, as new events could be added often.
- Storing precalculated statistical information would be difficult for the same reason as the previous.
- I have indexed all of the appropriate columns (pretty sure).
- I have considered combining these pivots into the *stats* table, but if there are better methods, I am more open to those.

Comment: 1) Are these fields 'users.u_thing' and 'categories.name' on covered indexes? 2) In addition, could you tell the counts of each tables?

Comment: @JianHuang I'm not sure to your first one offhand, whatever the basic "create index on" would provide. Currently users ~4000, events ~400, roles ~4000, categories ~150, stats ~170,000. As you can see users corresponds directly with events, and once live there will be well over 1,000,000 users.

Comment: @Sturn 1) Ask questions from a different angle. Are these fields 'users.u_thing' and 'categories.name' on any index? 2) From the counts of each table, good news. It should be very promising in performance tuning.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but yes, those fields are indexed.

Comment: Your database is not big. So it should not suffer from performance impact, at least, not at this point. It should be comparatively easier to tune the performance. That is the reason I say it is good news. Might I ask you that what database you use, the OS, and server configuration?

Comment: Mysq 5.6l, debian flavor. If you check out Laravel' s Homestead Vagrant distro that is exactly what I am using. While of course a non virtualized environment will be much faster, this will still cause problems with the eventual size of the tables.

Comment: Another probably relevant update is that with my one *user* my schema size is about 64mb.

Comment: have to say sorry that I cannot help further. I used to manage Oracle and MS Sql databases, and have no expertise in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

For JOIN-like operations, normal techniques like query or filtering from multiple tables are quite low efficient. Since the database has to fetch out all the roles satisfying the first where clause, and then check them one by one if they are in the table "users" and satisfying the second where clause "roles.user_id = roles.id" as your example lists.

Instead a most efficient way is to build a materialized view from all the underlying tables. You will think a materialized view a redundant data structure designed to accelerate your complex JOIN queries.

A post [JOIN via materialized view](https://github.com/LunarBaseEngin/LunarBase/wiki/JOIN-via-materialized-view) has an elaboration on this subject.

Comment: I'm waiting to see if other solutions are presented still. This goes strongly against a normalized structure, but this is currently the solution I have been leaning towards, as I don't see another way.